# SQL - create attribute output for unpivoted data

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, unpivot, cross-apply

I have a dataset which looks like the following:

```
Position_Date   Portfolio   Country   Weight   BM Weight
2017-09-30      Port1       Mexico    0.2      0.0
2017-09-30      Port1       Mexico    0.1      0.1
2017-09-30      Port1       USA       0.2      0.2
2017-09-30      Port1       USA       0.3      0.1
```

I would like to transform this stored data set into the following output using a SQL query:

```
Portfolio_Date  Portfolio  Dimension        Dimension_Value  Measure    Measure_Value
2017-09-30      Port1      Country          Mexico           Weight     0.3
2017-09-30      Port1      Country          Mexico           BM Weight  0.1
2017-09-30      Port1      Country          USA              Weight     0.5
2017-09-30      Port1      Country          USA              BM Weight  0.3
2017-09-30      Port1      Portfolio        Country          Weight     0.8
2017-09-30      Port1      Portfolio        Country          BM Weight  0.4
```

I was wondering what would be the efficient why to create the dataset?  Would I have to PIVOT the data to then UNPIVOT it to create my final dataset?  Or is there another way using CROSS APPLY with a GROUP BY that I could utilise which I have seen in other posts on this forum?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is much trickier than I first thought.  I would do the unpivot after doing the aggregation:

```
select t.Portfolio_Date, t.Portfolio,
       v.*
from (select t.Portfolio_Date, t.Portfolio,
             coalesce(country, 'Country') as dimension_value,  -- coalesce is a shortcut for getting the aggregated row
             coalesce(country, 'Portfolio') as dimension,
             sum(weight) as weight, sum(bm_weight) as bm_weight
      from t
      group by grouping sets ( (t.Portfolio_Date, t.Portfolio, country), (t.Portfolio_Date, t.Portfolio) )
     ) t outer apply
     (values (dimension, dimension_value, 'Weight', weight),
             (dimension, dimension_value, 'BM Weight', bm_weight)
     ) v(dimension, dimension_value, measure, measure_value);
```

Comment: Was just wondering if you could explain to me your comment about COALESCE being a shortcut for getting the aggregated row? @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @chrissyp . . . `grouping sets` returns `NULL` values for the aggregation rows.  Of course, the original keys could already have `NULL`, so it is a hacky (but very convenient) solution.  The correct way is to use `grouping()`, but that requires a `case`.